# How to remove or hide Component Tray from End-User ? XtraReports Winforms Devexpress?

Tags: winforms, devexpress, report

I want to hide or remove this component tray from end-user. How to complete this task.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @DmitryG

Code from [How to: Hide the Component Tray from End-Users in the Report Designer](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument5225)
should work

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using DevExpress.XtraReports.Design;
using DevExpress.XtraReports.UserDesigner;
// ...

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // Create an End-User Designer form.
    XRDesignForm designForm = new XRDesignForm();

    // Handle the DesignPanelLoaded event.
    designForm.DesignMdiController.DesignPanelLoaded +=
        new DesignerLoadedEventHandler(DesignMdiController_DesignPanelLoaded);

    // Load a report into the Designer.
    designForm.OpenReport(new XtraReport1());

    // Show the End-User Designer form, modally.
    designForm.ShowDialog();
}

// List the components in the Report Explorer, instead of the Component Tray.
void DesignMdiController_DesignPanelLoaded(object sender, DesignerLoadedEventArgs e) {
    ((XRDesignPanel)sender).ComponentVisibility = ComponentVisibility.ComponentTray;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Getting error on that ComponentVisibility in last line.

Comment: which devexpress version you are using?

Comment: DevExpress version 12.2

Comment: Documentation is supporting latest version of Devexpress. Try to upgrade your solution to latest version 13.2

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to read [documentation](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument2162) or contact [DevExpress Support](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/)?

[Create an End-User Reporting Application](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument15042) - This document lists examples for creating and customizing end-user reporting applications on various platforms.

Example:
[How to: Hide the Component Tray from End-Users in the Report Designer](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument5225)

Comment: Hi, I read already and used that code but getting error on that `ComponentVisibility` on last line that's why question asked here

Comment: error shows like "Does not contaion `ComponentVisibility` and no extension method `ComponentVisibility` accepting 1st argument.... "

Comment: Have you referenced all the [required](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument3189) assemblies (e.g. DevExpress.XtraReports.vxx.x.Extensions.dll for ConponentVisibility)?

Comment: Anyway, when you find an issue in DevExpress product or run into a problem when using it you should contact official DevExpress Support instead of posting all these multiple questions here. This is only way to get guaranteed, official and fast assistance.

Comment: Ya I referenced all the requires assemblies. `DevExpress.XtraReports.v12.2.dll` and `DevExpress.XtraReports.v12.2.Extensions.dll`